# Commute expected value and argmax for a noisy function with known argmax

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, time-series

I have the following question in
Given a random sequence $X_t, t\in[1,T]$, with $X_t = \varepsilon_t$ for $t=1,\ldots,d$ and $X_t = \mu + \varepsilon_t$ for $t=d+1,\ldots,T$ and $\mu>0,\varepsilon_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

I now define the function 
$$f(b,X)=\frac{\frac{\sum_{t=1}^b(X_t)}{b}-\frac{\sum_{t=b+1}^T(X_t)}{T-b}}{\sqrt{\frac{T}{b(T-b)}}}, b=1,\ldots,T-1.$$
The expression under the fraction is the root of the variance of the expression over the fraction. Thus for any $b$ $$f(b,X)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).$$
I also know the maximum of $\mathbb{E}|f(b,X)|$ is assumed at $d$ with 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|f(b,X)|b=d|\right]=\mu\sqrt{\frac{d(T-d)}{T}}
$$
and $\mathbb{E}|f(b,X)|$ is strictly monotonically increasing up to $d$ with
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|f(b,X)|b<d|\right]=\mu\sqrt{\frac{b}{T(T-b)}}(T-d)
$$
 and strictly monotonically decreasing from $d+1$ on with 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[|f(b,X)|b>d|\right]=\mu\sqrt{\frac{(T-b)}{Tb}}(d).
$$

How could I know establish, that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[argmax_{1\leq b < T}|f(b,X)|\right] = d =argmax_{1\leq b < T}\mathbb{E}|f(b,X)|
$$

Comment: where is b in th defintion of f(b, X)?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I edited the definition